# yq v4 get root keys based on existence of deeper keys

Tags: yaml, yq

I have this structure:

```
foo:
  image: 123

bar:
  image: 456

baz:
  config: "my config"
```

and I'd like to print the root keys (i.e. foo, bar, baz) based on the existence of the child "image"

In yq version 3 I could do this:

```
$ yq read test.yaml --printMode p "*.image" | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'
foo
bar
```

But I can't find the equivalent in v4. The yq + jq solution would be:

```
$ yq -j e test.yaml | jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value | has("image")) | [.key][]' 
foo
bar
```

Any idea how to do this with yq v4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [path operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/path) to get the path of the matching object containing the tag `image`

```sh
yq e '.[] | select(has("image")) | path | .[]' yaml
```